# Can I remove double quotes from keys in this json but not the values?

Tags: python, json

I have the following json string:

```
'{"start_time": {"_gte": "2021-10-10 19:00:00"}, "end_time": {"_gte": "2021-10-10 19:30:00"}}'
```

and I need to get:

```
'{start_time: {_gte: "2021-10-10 19:00:00"}, end_time: {_gte: "2021-10-10 19:30:00"}}'
```

Is this possible?

Comment: I don't know why you would need that string, but the first step is to decode the JSON into a Python `dict`. Once you have that, you can construct the desired string using the keys and values of the `dict`.

Comment: And tomorrow, you or your colleague are going to post a question asking how to parse the latter string.

Comment: @chepner Thanks, I need it because the json string is turned into a graphql query which requires double quotation marks around the time stamp

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode rude :)

Comment: @fourloops You are better off generating a proper GraphQL query from a data structure than trying to manipulate JSON as a plain string directly.

Comment: @chepner Could you please elaborate on this thanks - quite new to this

Comment: `d = json.load(your_string)`. Now proceed to build the desired string from `d`, which is *not* as simple as just doing something like `str(d)`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess something like this should work:

```py
import json
from typing import List, Tuple, Any


string = '{"start_time": {"_gte": "2021-10-10 19:00:00"}, "end_time": {"_gte": "2021-10-10 19:30:00"}}'


class MyDict(dict):
    def __repr__(self):
        return '{' + ', '.join([f'{k}: {v!r}' for k, v in self.items()]) + '}'


def hook_fn(value: List[Tuple[str, Any]]):
    return MyDict(value)


print(json.loads(string, object_pairs_hook=hook_fn))
```

it prints:

```
{start_time: {_gte: '2021-10-10 19:00:00'}, end_time: {_gte: '2021-10-10 19:30:00'}}
```